# How to correct two initial capitals using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to correct the second capital letter of each word into lower case after entering the third letter in lower case?

Example:

"INput" will be corrected into "Input" (since the first and second letter are capital letters)
"INP" will not be corrected.

A function that converts a string would suffice:

```
function autoCorrect(input) {
  return "corrected input";
}
```

My question is different to existing posts like

> Using Javascript, how to capitalize each word in a String excluding
> acronyms

> Is there a way to ignore acronyms in a title case method

> Convert string to Title Case with JavaScript

I don't want to convert a string to title case in such a way that every new word begins with a capital(uppercase) letter but correct two consecutive upper case letters at the beginning of each word.

This seems to work, even if it is not the most elagant solution. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.

```js
    String.prototype.isUpperCase = function() {
      return this.toString() === this.toUpperCase();
    }
    
    var str = "SOme Text THat NO YEs END";
    var str2 = str[0] || '';
    
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      const next1 = str[i + 1] || '';
      const next2 = str[i + 2] || '';
      
      if (str[i].isUpperCase() && next1.isUpperCase() && !next2.isUpperCase()) {
        str2 += str[i+1].toLowerCase() || '';
      } else {
        str2 += str[i+1]  || '';
      }
      
    
    }
    
    console.log(str2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `after entering the third letter in lower case`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a regular expression is what you need.

The following regular expression matches word characters is in the range A-Z (ie. English uppercase) if that uppercase character is preceded by another word character at the start of a word (negative lookahead assertion `(?<=\b\w)`) and if that uppercase character is succeeded by one or more lowercase English word characters (lookahead assertion `(?=[a-z]+)`).

Does this do what you want?

```js
const PATTERN = /(?<=\b\w)([A-Z])(?=[a-z]+)/gu
const fix = (s) => 
    s.replaceAll(PATTERN, (_, match) => match.toLowerCase())

console.log(fix('As I aPproached the IBM building, I was asked for ID. Note ALSo.')) // 'As I approached the IBM building, I was asked for ID. Note ALSo.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the first two lines, (improvement)

```js
var str = "SOme Text THat NO YEs END";
var str2 = str[0] || '';

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  const next1 = str[i + 1] || '';
  const next2 = str[i + 2] || '';
  
  if (str[i].isUpperCase() && next1.isUpperCase() && !next2.isUpperCase()) {
    str2 += str[i+1].toLowerCase() || '';
  } else {
    str2 += str[i+1]  || '';
  }
}
console.log(str2);
```